# Об употреблении слова "либо" без "не" и с "не"

Tags: семантика

Предположим, что на столике лежат туз, король, дама и валет.

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Либо возьми туза, либо возьми короля, либо возьми даму, либо возьми валета." полностью совпадает по смыслу с указанием "Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета.",
- указание "Либо не бери туза, либо не бери короля, либо не бери даму, либо не бери валета." полностью совпадает по смыслу с указанием "Не бери либо туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета."?

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант

"Либо возьми туза, либо возьми короля, либо возьми даму, либо возьми валета." Это вторая часть ситуации, которая в полном объеме, к примеру, может выглядеть так: либо пропусти ход, либо возьми одну из 4-х карт.

"Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета. Это означает: возьми одну из 4-х карт. Это самостоятельная ситуация.

С точки зрения коммуникативности, обе фразы неточны, так как в обоих случаях не требуется перечисления 4-х карт. Кроме того, между собой они не совпадают.

Второй вариант

"Либо не бери туза, либо не бери короля, либо не бери даму, либо не бери валета." Это также  только  вторая часть ситуации, которая в полном объеме может выглядеть так: либо возьми все карты, либо не бери ни одной из  4-х карт.

Делаем обязательную замену: "Не бери ни туза, ни короля, ни даму, ни валета. Это означает: не бери ни одну из 4-х карт. Это самостоятельная ситуация.

Комментарий тот же.

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленные сведения.

Comment: Именно с этой точки зрения и надо рассматривать Ваши вопросы. Любые наши высказывания решают одну из трех задач: передать информацию, задать вопрос или попросить что-либо сделать. Например: "Ты опять двойку получил? Можешь не рассказывать,что ты ни в чем не виноват. Быстро садись за уроки!"  Все сообщения должны быть корректно оформлены, то есть быть верными семантически, грамматически и коммуникативно.

Comment: Извините, что отвлёк Вас от обсуждения вопроса о слитном либо раздельном написании "не" и "спеша" в предложении "Черепицею шурша, крыша едет не спеша.".

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что в первых двух указаниях, как я поняла, предлагается взять одну из перечисленных карт. Разница состоит только  в способе оформления мысли: в первом предложении нарушен порядок слов. Но по смыслу, Вы, Галактион, совершенно правы,они совпадают. А в двух вторых указаниях, по-моему, есть разница в значениях.Указание "Либо не бери туза......" предлагает либо НЕ БРАТЬ, либо...., логично предположить, что далее должно быть предложено что -то ВЗЯТЬ или что-то сделать. Но этого нет. Второе указание понятно "Не бери либо туза.......". Дальнейшее перечисление необязательно, то есть не бери НИЧЕГО. Таким образом, я думаю, что два  первых указания совпадают по смыслу, а два вторых нет.